How find information in adjacent cells merge cell docx document with Python
I'm using the python-docx library to extract data from a MS Word document.
More precisely, I'm trying to find and merge cells in tables, extract the content of the found cell, and register it as the key of a dictionary.
Then I want to register the contents of the cells located to the right of the found merged cell as the corresponding value of said dictionary. This information can span multiple lines.
I did not achieve to:

gather information from those cells (from all rows corresponding to the merged cell) that are next to the right;
display the row numbers of the merged cells, but only the last row is taken into account;
display the number of the first row in the merged cell.

I would appreciate your help
This is what I've written so far:
def iter_cells(table):
    for r, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for c, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            # check if the cell equals the previous cell either horizontally or vertically
            if (r > 0 and c < len(table.rows[r - 1].cells) and cell._tc is table.rows[r - 1].cells[c]._tc) \
                or (c > 0 and cell._tc is row.cells[c - 1]._tc):
                print('row', r, 'cell', c, 'is a duplicate', 'text in cell',table.cell(r,c).text)
                #print(table.cell(r,c).text)
                continue
            yield cell



If you want to create a dictionary, why do you need the row numbers? Are you expecting duplicate keys (apart from the merged cells)? If not, looks like you can just check if a key already exists. If not, add the key-value pair, if yes, update the value. If you do expect duplicate keys, please explain what you would like the new key to be. E.g., same key with an incremental value: "key", "key_1", "key_2"?

It would in general be useful to see a [mre], together with the desired dictionary based on the sample provided.

If I'm not mistaken, you're fetching a table from an MS Word document, is that right? Also, it is unclear if you want to merge cells vertically (merge rows) or horizontally (merge columns)

@ouroboros1 Let's say I'm looking for the word "industrial building", and it turns out that this word is located in the combined cells vertically (3 lines) and opposite this combined cell (on the right) there are non-merged cells - 3 lines and in each there are words corresponding to this word "industrial building"

@globglogabgalab yep. Add picture.
